# Doughnut graph is not working in d3 with two Arc object dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a doughnut graph, I have two entities to represent on the dougnut graph and need to show one with thick line i.e wider arc and one with narrow arc.

I tried to achieve like this. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ecaxpk07/4/)

I made two arc in beginning arc and arc2 and in the function

```
 var slice_path = slice_group.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d,i){console.log(d); return arc;})
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
```

here in the third line I want to do something like this

```
.attr("d", function(d,i){
   if(based on condition in d.series) 
      return arc;
   else
      return arc2;
})
```

But I'm not able to make it work, If i write it as

```
 .attr("d", function(d,i){console.log(d); return arc;})
```

It do not work ,but if i write as

```
 .attr("d", arc)
```

It works.

Could you guide me in case... !..

Comment: For use with an anonymous proxy function, you must pass the arguments: `.attr("d", function(d,i){console.log(d); return arc(d,i);})`

Comment: Thanks @Imperative it worked I got as arc was not getting d,i it was not working thanks..........!